# Proof Verification: Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

May you tell me if my proof is correct? Thank you so much!

Here is the problem:

[image: Abstract Algebra problems]

***Proof by induction.***

By the points 3 and 4, the left inverse of g, L, and the right inverse of g, R, exists. We need to prove that L=R for any finite set that follow 1) 2) 3) 4).

If g is the only element of G, as G is closed gg=g then g is the identity element e. Then L=g=R.

If a, g are the only elements of G, a and g are different. As G is closed aa=e and gg=e. Then L=R.

Suppose that G has n-1 elements, and suppose that for each of those different elements L=R.

Now consider that G has n elements, all the n-1 elements of the previous set plus one extra element. Let call the n element x. Then by the points 3 and 4, Lx=xR=e.

If L=x then R=x and L=R. If L=R we are done. Then we need to suppose that L is not equal to R, and that L and R are one of the first n-1 elements that by the inductive step, all the elements have left and right inverse and they are equal.

Then Lx=xR=e implies ax=xb=e.

Also, ax=e implies x=$a^{-1}$

Additionally, xb= e implies x=$b^{-1}$

Then $a^{-1}$ = $b^{-1}$ implies a=b. Then L=R.

***Q.E.D.***

For the problem 30. One example is the infinite set of the even numbers. The operation is the common multiplication. It is not a group for many reasons, one of them is that the identity element of multiplication, 1, is not a member of the set. However, premises 1) 2) 3) and 4) work on the set.

Comment: Your proof is not right, or at least not clear. You say that (3) tells you there's a left inverse - but it doesn't. All it says is that you can cancel. That's what makes your correct answer to problem 30 work.

Comment: Actually, the answer to problem 30 also requires a correction (or at least a clarification). It will be correct if you say that it's the infinite set of all **positive** even numbers.  The infinite set of all _integer_ even numbers doesn't satisfy the cancellation conditions due to $0$ being an element of the set.

Comment: @zipirovich Thank you for the correction! I appreciate your comment!

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for your ideas! I did not notice your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but your proof is incorrect under many respects.

To begin with, in order to prove existence of inverses you need to prove the existence of a neutral element, which is not stated in the hypotheses. Also, induction cannot be used, unless you prove the subset with $n-1$ elements is closed under the operation (which it isn't, because of Lagrange's theorem).

For $a\in G$, consider the maps $\lambda_a\colon G\to G$, $\lambda_a(x)=a*x$, and $\rho_a\colon G\to G$, $\rho_a(x)=x*a$.

By points 3 and 4, these maps are injective, so also surjective because $G$ is finite. Fix $a_0\in G$; by surjectivity of $\lambda_{a_0}$, there exists $r\in G$ such that $a_0*r=a_0$.

We want to show that $a*r=a$, for every $a\in G$. By surjectivity of $\rho_{a_0}$, there exists $a_1\in G$ with $a=a_1*a_0$, so
$$
a*r=(a_1*a_0)*r=a_1*(a_0*r)=a_1*a_0=a
$$

With a similar technique, we can prove there exists $l\in G$ with $l*a=a$, for every $a\in G$.

In particular, $r=l*r=l$, so we have found that $G$ has a neutral element $l=r=e$.

Now, given $a\in G$, there exists $a'\in G$ with $a*a'=e$ and also $a''\in G$ with $a'*a''=e$. Then
$$
a''=e*a''=(a*a')*a''=a*(a'*a'')=a*e=a
$$
and so $a'$ is the two-sided inverse of $a$.

---

The natural numbers under addition provide a simple counterexample for the infinite case.

Comment: Question: you answer says that I cannot use induction because "unless you prove the subset with nn elements is closed under the operation." However, premise 1) says "G is closed under the operation." Beautiful answer! Thank you for your help! It motivated me that I need to study more about functions and many other things of course! –

Comment: @Beginner Sorry, I was referring to the point where you consider the set with $n-1$ “previous elements”: that set is certainly not closed under the operation.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! Why you wrote that "is certainly not closed under the operation"? Please explain me.

Comment: @Beginner If a group has $n>2$ elements, no subset having $n-1$ elements can be closed under the operation, otherwise it would be a subgroup; Lagrange's theorem disallows it.

Answer (score 2):

"By the points 3 and 4, the left inverse of g, L, and the right inverse of g, R, exists"

I'd prefer you to be explicit about this. Why must there be $a^{-1}$ to pre-multiply $ab = ac$ by?

"If a, g are the only elements of G, a and g are different. As G is closed aa=e and gg=e"

Why must $aa = a$ and $gg=g$ both be simultaneously false? (This follows from the existence of left inverses, but I'm not satisfied that you've proved it.)

Comment: Thank you Patrick! Wonderful idea! I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Besides what @PatrickStevens and @EthanBolker already pointed out in their great answers and comments, there's also a problem with using induction here. The first $n-1$ elements may not satisfy the four given conditions — they may not be closed under the $*$ operation (and in fact, it's very unlikely that they are). So you can't invoke the induction hypothesis here — if the conditions aren't satisfied, you can't draw the desired conclusion.

Finiteness here is a crucial condition, but not for induction. Here's a hint to get you started, which also shows why finiteness of $G$ is important here. For convenience of notation, let's say $n=|G|$ is the number of elements in $G$. Let's fix some element $a\in G$, and consider the set $\{a*x\mid x\in G\}$. This set has exactly $n$ elements in it, which all have to be distinct by property 3. So these $n$ elements are precisely the $n$ elements of $G$. (This is the part that may be violated in the infinite case.) In particular, one of them is $a$ itself, so there exists an element $e$ such that $a*e=a$.

Note that this $e$ isn't known to be the identity element yet! For now, we just know that it works as the identity only for $a$ and only from the right. But it certainly is the natural candidate to be the identity. So next you should show that also $e*a=a$ for this $a$, and then that $b*e=e*b=b$ for any $b\in G$. Only after you have your identity element are you ready to handle inverses.